What keyboard shortcuts disable the keyboard?
Problem: My cat has twice managed to disable my keyboards, both the built-in laptop keyboard (a ThinkPad P14s) and the one attached via USB. I assume this is by the purry monster pressing some combination of keys, but I cannot find which key combination would do this.
Context: My cat sneaks to my laptop whenever I do not look at her and, sends emails, or IMs someone, or triggers some keyboard combination I have to get out of. This is acceptable because I am working on a Cat Laptop Sleeping Deck (was: Cat Repeller but my family threatened me) that I will open source (this is a deck attached to the laptop).
One thing I cannot understand is how she managed twice to disable my keyboards.
Everything else is operational: the OS is not frozen and the mouse cursor moves fine and interacts with applications without issue. The only thing that does not work are keyboards. This is specifically not a matter of a USB cable gone loose - the laptop's built-in keyboard is disabled as well.
No combination (even Ctrl-Alt-Del) works, the only way to get out of this mess is to reboot. Or get rid of the cat. But yes, reboot.
Question: what key combination is the furry fiend pressing that disables the keyboards, and/or what combination will return the keyboards to life?
In case the context can help someone, this is a typical case of the cat disturbing me during work.


I don't think it's about getting dryer, it's just not too answerable. I'm close to casting my own close vote, since there's nothing on Windows that could cause this easily. If I were you I'd add at minimum the laptop model as random shortcut like Fn + F11 could exist for it.

@Destroy666 thanks for the suggestion. An answer such as "this does not exist in Windows 11" is fine (and will be added to cats magic) but yes, good idea to add the model just in case (and I will have a look at the Fn-X keys too)

Even though it is jocular, referencing the death of even the fiendliest of felines may be attracting close votes. Just a guess. I've removed those references and made a few other edits I think keep the general tone of the question while focusing on the problem and requested solution a little more clearly. Hopefully this will help stave off the close votes.

I am not aware of any keyboard combinations for disabling keyboards. If there were a laptop hotkey, I'd be surprised if it impacted both the onboard and external keyboards (I can see disabling the onboard when using an external, but not needing to disable both). This all makes me wonder if your computer has some function to block the keyboards when they detect obvious pet activity. I've never heard of such a feature, but there's plenty of real things I haven't heard of.

Look for another culprit. 1. AFAIK, there is no simple keyboard shortcut to disable the keyboard. Windows+L will send the PC to lock screen, but keyboard still works. 2. If it's very dry, cat's fur rubbing against plastic keys might be creating ESD, but that's as likely to destroy IC's as to simply shut key input.

Finally, it COULD still be a faulty USB connection. It is entirely possible that your built-in laptop keyboard connects through an internal USB header. While you mention the mouse still works, how is the mouse connected? Do other USB devices still work once the keyboards stop working? Do they work in the same port(s) the external keyboard is connected to? Try pressing on your computer in a way similar to how the cat was: do USB connections stop or falter?

@music2myear thanks, I appreciate the effort  (with the updates EDIT: the updates were really good, thanks). There must also be a cultural context - I am French and we are generally way more "second degree" (well, except for baguette, croissant , wine, cheese and a few other things which are the best in the world and we do not tolerate criticism in any form)

@music2myear I will try your ideas. The mouse and external USB are connected side by side to the docking station. Apart form the mouse, other USB devices that were connected these two times (different every time) worked fine. I will try to mimic the gymnastics of the cat when this happens again.

Question: If there were a key combination to disable the keyboard, how would you enable it again? Answer: When you disable the keyboard, an icon appears on the status bar. You click it with the mouse to enable the keyboard. Make it so.

See also: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard

Wild idea: if it happens so regularly, perhaps it's not a specific button combination but rather a very non-specific one? What if you keep a whole lot of keyboard keys pressed down for a lengthy amount of time? Perhaps some driver/microchip decides that this is an indicator of a hardware fault and therefore disables the keyboard? I've never heard of something like this, but I wouldn't be surprised of some custom Lenovo thing like that.

Some Lenovo laptops (including P14) have a "Quick Clean" mode that you can turn on with a key combination:

Depending on the model, your computer might support the Lenovo Quick Clean feature. The preinstalled Lenovo Quick Clean enables you to temporarily disable the keyboard, screen, trackpad, and trackpoint pointing device for cleaning.
from: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t14_t15_p14s_p15s_ug_en.pdf

Press the Fn and right Shift keys at the same time to access it

I feel compelled to add that Fn and rShift keys distance reminds me very closely of the size of the stride of my cats.

Thanks a lot for the hint, but this is not this (but maybe the other answer)

Why is it that, when there's an obscure keyboard shortcut that'll lock your machine and leave you spending hours or days trying to resolve it... a cat will readily and exactly find it?? :P

I had a client with this exact problem the other day. The keyboard shortcut that enabled this was to hold the right shift key for eight seconds, something that a cat could easily do. What it did was not disable the keyboard, but enable filter keys, an adaptation designed for people with Parkinsons or the equivalent who hit keys multiple times when they only want to hit once. Filter Keys makes it so that a key press does not register until a key has been held for a short while, I think half a second. Open the Adaptations menu (the little man icon in the lower right of the login screen) and disable Filter Keys and you should be good.

Oh thank you - I will give that a try. It happened again a moment ago and I discovered that the Fn key still works (and its combinations). This is the only one I found working. I will disable Adaptations and see how it goes! EDIT: it's not this as it prevents repetition but doe snot disable the keyboard, but thsisi very good to know!

It feels like it disables the keyboard because a normal keypress is too short to register. Checking the adaptations menu is still a good idea, because other adaptations can have similarly disruptive effects.

Upvote. Had a similar experience with Windows laptop keyboard appearing disabled prior to log-in prompt (it was in sleep mode initially, and then kids unsuccessfully tried to break in).  Needed to avoid an obvious remedy (to reboot) because the loaded session had too many programs open and i didn't want to lose their state. It turned out to be StickyKeys, more aptly should be named StinkyKeys! ))

Fn+F7 toggles lock and unlock (can't use keyboard).

Which laptop is this for?

Toggles touchpad, not the keyboard on my Acer laptop

This starts the display choice (like Win-P) on my ThinkPad.

In general, Fn+F combinations are vendor, and often product line or even model, specific. That is for good reasons - any non-Fn combination could potentially be used by an ordinary application (so therefore you don't want to have it do a machine-specific thing) and most desktop keyboards don't have an Fn key so you can't use Fn combinations in an ordinary application.
